# Is IoMT technologically different to IoT?

Tags: protocols, standards

It seems from papers such as [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9590881) that IoMT is just IoT for medical devices with no new technological developments.

Is there anything about IoMT such as a standard that somehow differentiates it from IoT?

Comment: IoT is just a very vague marketing term, IoMT is probably just the same thing, just focused on a particular application (rather than a class or type of devices).

Comment: That's what I'm seeing.  I have to write a report on IoMT for University so am inclined to say IoMT is not novel and just a marketing term for IoT in conjunction with medical devices.

Comment: The point about IoMT is probably not that it’s a different technology, but the application has specific requirements in terms of data security, safety (consider implanted devices such as pacemakers), battery life, difficult environments (within a person, or in a crowded environment), etc. It may require specific technologies which are not usually needed in other circumstances, or additional levels of safeguards.

Comment: Fwiw, unlikely pace makers will ever join IoMT as micro shocks are extremely dangerous for anyone with a pacemaker.  All the conditions you outline exist in other applications, e.g. automotive.  Until a standard exists, IoMT is just marketing IMHO.

Comment: A pacemaker is definitely a “Medical Thing”, and many can be connected, so that would clearly make them part of “IoMT”, even if that’s indirect. [Security issues with such pacemakers have been raised](https://www.google.fr/search?q=hack+pacemaker). That makes it very clearly an important topic in the field.

Comment: Agree, a pacemaker is definitely a “Medical Thing”.  AFAIK, pacemakers are not IoMT rather an ECG analyzer reports the heart (pace maker) activity and that can be an IoT device.  However, apologies as I jumped to fast to say you're wrong, I'm not as pacemaker expert.